# Get date from JS Timestamp

Tags: javascript, date

I have an array "data" which looks like

```
[1298214000000, "123456"]
```

with

```
data[0] = 1298214000000
```

When trying to convert the timestamp of data[0] to a date I

**EXPECT**

```
Sun Feb 20 2011 16:00:00 GMT+0100
```

**INSTEAD I GET**

```
Mon Mar 24 2014 23:27:43 GMT+0100
```

Which is always the current date

I used

```
console.log(Date(data[0])
```

and also

```
console.log(Date(data[0].toString()));
```

None worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Date` is a constructor, so use it as one:

```
console.log(new Date(data[0]).toString());
```

`new Date()` will create a new `Date` object.

Simply calling the function results in a specific behaviour of `Date` - that is return the current date as a string (the *string* part documented in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), but I did not find specification for the *current* part).

Note that this is consistent with other primitive constructors:

```
new Boolean(): [object Boolean]
Boolean(): false

new String(): [object String]
String(): ""
```

Comment: so simple. thanks. Would have spent hours on that :/
btw: .toString() is not necessary.